# Using core data in an existing project

Tags: iphone, core-data

I need to use core data to persist data for my project, what I have done so far compiles well, but when I actually start storing things using core data, the program just quits, and I don't know the reason. I set up all the required components for core data in the appDelegate file, and I want to store data in a `viewController` called `DetailViewController`. Here is what I have done:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set the tab bar controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//this is what I added, reference managedObjectContext in the detail view controller.

    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    return YES;
}
```

All components for core data have been implemented

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
            return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];

    return managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                                           stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyProjectName.sqlite"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                              initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                             configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

When I try to call a method in the detail view to store data, the program quits.

```
-(IBAction) addItem {
    Info *info = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Info" 
                                                   inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    info.name = item.name;
}
```

`item` is the current object in the detail view, `Info` is the model class file. Do I miss something here?

Thanks!

Update:

The error message in the console is:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Info''

But I do have a Info.xcdatamodel file in the "Resources" folder, and entity name is "Info".

Comment: Do you have entity `@"Info"` in your model? And what error is displayed in debug console?

Comment: Yes, the model file has been created, the entity name is "Info".

Comment: Is `managedObjectContext != nil` ?

Comment: What error is displayed n the debug console?

Comment: Where did your Info class come from? Did you generate it from an entity?

Comment: Yes, I generate the model class out of my data model file I created.

Comment: Check your managed object model method. You need to specify the model file there and at the moment you are passing nil to it.

Comment: @Rog, hi, can you help me modify those three methods, because I copied them from a reference, my data model file is called "Info.xcdatamodel" and the entity within it is called "Info", thanks~

Comment: Check out @Mundi's answer. It's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call `[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]`?

Also, perhaps your bundle loading routine does not work correctly. Try loading the managedObjectContext like this:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ModelName" 
   withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] 
   initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
return __managedObjectModel;
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot find a file or directory ended up with "momd" extension, and now I am having another trouble, when I delete the original model file and build a new one with the same entity in it, the error says "Can't merge models with two different entities".

Comment: Seems like your project file is messed up referencing a managed object model in some other folder. Remove all references to the model, both on disk and in the project explorer (here is the error, I think). Then recreate. Reset the iOS Simulator, too. This should solve this confusion.

Comment: Ahh, I finally solved it, just change the "momd" to "mom"...Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that in your detail view controller you either aren't synthesizing `managedObjectContext` or you aren't initializing it when creating your detail view controller.  Check that both of those are being done.  If that doesn't solve the problem, please check the console output after the crash and post any relevant information there in an update to your question.

Comment: I have synthesized it in .m file, I didn't init it because I already referenced it in the appDelegate file, and have managedObjectContext in the appDelegate assigned to the one of the detail view controller.